# Conflict Validation on form.$error.required and form.$invalid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

**UPDATE: IT HAS BEEN CONFIRMED THAT THIS IS AN ANGULAR BUG**

**Check: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14734#issuecomment-224558516**

The case is, I am trying to create a datepicker field that detects if the input is an invalid date(The months and days validity is also included like 2015-02-30 is invalid because there is no February 30) and is also required. So, I created a custom form validity via directive to detect the invalid date. The custom validity is working fine, however, seems like the $error.required and $invalid does not sync since I have used "ngModel.$validators.available".

Here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/NuDGB64IetpcsaVB03T7?p=preview

You will notice in plunker that the $error.required is **true** but the $invalid is Just **blank** but turns to true when you input an invalid date and false if the date input is valid. In short, the form is not considered invalid when the input is blank which is very needed for my ng-class

The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/flick/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <form ng-controller="myCtrl" name="bioManagementForm" novalidate>
          Degree: <br />
          <p>Invalid Input: -- {{ bioManagementForm.in_company_since.$invalid }}</p>
          <p>Required -- {{ bioManagementForm.in_company_since.$error.required }}</p>
          <input class="form-control input-form since" ng-class="{ 'error': bioManagementForm.in_company_since.$invalid && notifications }" type="text" id="in_company_since" name="in_company_since" ng-model="input.in_company_since" ng-required="true" datepicker>
    </form>
  </body>

  <script>
    // Code goes here

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []); 


    myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

    });


   myApp.directive('datepicker', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require : 'ngModel',
            link : function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                console.log(ngModel);
                datePatternCounter = [];
                // $(function(){
                    if(!scope.viewOnly){
                        element.attr("placeholder", "YYYY-MM-DD");
                    }
                    element.datepicker({
                        changeYear: true, 
                        changeMonth: true, 
                        yearRange: "1900:+50", 
                        showButtonPanel: true,
                        closeText: 'Clear',
                        dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
                        onSelect:function (date) {
                            ngModel.$setViewValue(date);
                            scope.$apply();
                        },
                        // Custom function that clears the date value of the model when the "Clear" button is clicked on the datepicker
                        onClose: function(date){
                            var event = arguments.callee.caller.caller.arguments[0];
                            if(Number(date) && date.length == 8){
                                // alert("dean");
                                year = date.slice(0, 4);
                                month = date.slice(4, 6);
                                day = date.slice(6, 8);
                                newDate = year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
                                ngModel.$setViewValue(newDate);
                                ngModel.$render();
                            }else{
                                // alert("armada");
                                // Code if with dash
                                // Do nothing
                            }
                            // ngModel.$error.datePattern
                            if(event['type'] == 'click'){
                                ngModel.$setViewValue(undefined);
                                ngModel.$render();
                            }
                        },
                        beforeShow: function (e, t) {
                            id = document.querySelector( '#ui-datepicker-div' );
                            angular.element(id).addClass('HideTodayButton');
                            if(element.hasClass('birth_date')){
                                element.datepicker("option", "maxDate", 0);
                            }
                        },
                    });
                // });
          // START Syntax to check if the date is valid or not in real time
                ngModel.$validators.available = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                    if(modelValue){
                        var check = modelValue.split('-');
                        var y = parseInt(check[0], 10);
                        var m = parseInt(check[1], 10);
                        var d = parseInt(check[2], 10);
                        var date = new Date(y,m-1,d);
                        if (date.getFullYear() == y && date.getMonth() + 1 == m && date.getDate() == d) {
                            check = true;
                        } else {
                            check = false;
                            name = ngModel.$name;
                            if(datePatternCounter.indexOf(name) == -1){
                                datePatternCounter.push(name);
                                element.parent().siblings("span.errors").append('<span class="invalid-date" ng-if="'+ngModel.$error.available+'"> * Invalid Date <br /></span>');
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    return check;
                }
                // END Syntax to check if the date is valid or not
            }
        }
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: The binding `ng-model="input.in_company_since"` seems wrong, should it read `ng-model="in_company_since"`?

Comment: That's not the case,, Actually this is only a part of the template.. I have a lot of inputs other input ng-models are "input.in_company_until", "input.in_company" for those ng-models to be stored in a single json object

Answer (score 2):

Change your date validator to return `true` in case of empty value:

```
ngModel.$validators.available = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
    if(modelValue){
        var check = modelValue.split('-');
        var y = parseInt(check[0], 10);
        var m = parseInt(check[1], 10);
        var d = parseInt(check[2], 10);
        var date = new Date(y,m-1,d);
        if (date.getFullYear() == y && date.getMonth() + 1 == m && date.getDate() == d) {
            check = true;
        } else {
            check = false;
            name = ngModel.$name;
            if(datePatternCounter.indexOf(name) == -1){
                datePatternCounter.push(name);
                element.parent().siblings("span.errors").append('<span class="invalid-date" ng-if="'+ngModel.$error.available+'"> * Invalid Date <br /></span>');
            }
        }
        return check; // true or false when value is not empty
    }
    return true; // empty value should be handled by ng-required, we only check format here, so return true
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for an explanation.. I wanna know if this is a bug of angular?

Comment: Nevermind, It is confirmed that this is an angularbug. Check: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14734#issuecomment-224558516

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada, the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) clearly states that _validation operation must return a `true` or `false`_. I wouldn't call it a bug, since you are returning `undefined`. Changes proposed in the answer solve the problem.

Comment: The contributors counted it as a bug.. As for my end the "$validators.available" should have just read or considered the $error.available not the whole invalidity of the input